# Parallel workflow only runs one item

Tags: powershell, parallel.foreach

I have created a workflow in my script that goes out on the network a "tails" the logs of an application. I am looking for an error flag to take corrective action and alert the helpdesk `Send-Spark` function

For some reason, the foreach is only "tailing" one array item instead of all of them in parallel.

```
workflow Get-Tails {

  param ($POS)#Array with terminal names


  ForEach -parallel ($item in $POS)
  { 
    write-host "Scanning "$item -ForegroundColor red -BackgroundColor white   
    Get-Content -Path "\\$item\c$\path\to\logs\Agent.log" -Tail 1 -Wait | % {if ($_ -match '<Status Code="NotReady">') {Send-Spark $item}} 

    }

}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: powershell does not accept a -parallel parameter for either foreach or ForEach-Object.

Comment: I thought only in a workflow you can use  -parallel. BTW I am not getting an error.

Comment: Yeah, I have no clue about workflows.

Answer (score 0):

`I hope you have to use inlinescript command to execute the commands which you kept inside the foreach-parallel loop.


I have modified your code.

Step 1: Execute the below powershell code to create a workflow

workflow Get-Tails {
param ($POS)#Array with terminal names
  ForEach -parallel($item in $POS)
  { 
    InlineScript{
    write-host ("Scanning "+$Using:item) -ForegroundColor red -BackgroundColor white   
    Get-Content -Path "\$Using:item\c$\path\to\logs\Agent.log" -Tail 1 -Wait | % {if ($_ -match '') {Send-Spark $Using:item}} 
    }
    }
}

STEP 2: Call a workflow in powershell

Get-Tails

SAMPLE Execution with Output:

#######################

PS C:\windows\system32> workflow test
{
$a=@(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Foreach -Parallel($i in $a)
{
InlineScript {"Inline A1 = $Using:i"}
}
}

PS C:\windows\system32> test
Inline A1 = 7
Inline A1 = 8
Inline A1 = 6
Inline A1 = 10
Inline A1 = 9
Inline A1 = 3
Inline A1 = 5
Inline A1 = 2
Inline A1 = 4
Inline A1 = 1
`

Please let me know if you need any assistance.

Please visit for more information :
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented your example and now I can see the terminals I am scanning, just like your output, I just can't see the logs "tailing". How can I know is really pulling the info?